# Angular unit test: unable to change property value after DOM click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-test

So I'm new to Angular testing and I wanted to test if my property selectedHeroes changed after I clicked a button in the DOM. I tested as well if the method onSelect() gets called when I trigger a button click in my test and it does.

However, when I test if the selectedHero property value is now truthy. It says that  it is still undefined. Can you guys see why?

**Test file**

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let userService;

  let el;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    const userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['getUserData']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService}]
    })
    .compileComponents();

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should change selectedHeroes property after click', fakeAsync(() => {
fixture.detectChanges();

let spy = spyOn(component, 'onSelect');
el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('li')).nativeElement.click();

tick();

expect(component.onSelect).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.selectedHero).toBeTruthy();

  }));
});
```

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{

  selectedHero;
  heroes = [{id: 1, name: 'superman'}, {id: 2, name: 'Iron man'}];

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSelect(hero) {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">...</div>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tired to run fixture.detectChanges() after emitting the click event?

Answer (score 1):

When you create jasmine `spy` then you should not forget to call `callThrough`, otherwise the original function will not be called.

`let spy = spyOn(component, 'onSelect').and.callThrough();`

Comment: What do you mean by the original function ? I think it should be the new mock function ``onSelect`` no ?

Comment: I mean the original `TestComponent.onSelect` function, which does `this.selectedHero = hero;`. This function is replaced with spy and spy does nothing, so the selected hero is not assigned. When you add `callThrough` then the spy calls the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was the same for me and I had a function like this:

```
public getCarriers(): void {
            this.lookupService.getCarriers(this.receiveService.controls.carrier.value || '');
            this.isCarrierBlurred = false;
        }
```

My test was something like that

```
it('should get all carriers when carrier input keyup triggered', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'getCarriers').and.callThrough();
        (mockReceiveService.controls as any).carrier = {value: ''};
        const carrierInputDE = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#carrier-input'));
        carrierInputDE.triggerEventHandler('keyup', null);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component.getCarriers).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(mockLookupService.getCarriers).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.isCarrierBlurred).toBeFalsy();
    });
```

But two last `expect`s always failed. It seemed it was because nothing happened in `getCarriers` function but after debugging I found that I have a error in second line on my test (in this case: `(mockReceiveService.controls as any).carrier = {value: ''};`) that prevent to the code run completely.

After debugging, I resolved the issue and then everything goes well.